# How to get dowload initiator programmatically?

Tags: internet-explorer, fiddler, developer-tools

[image: screenshot for question]

Is there a way to receive the same information as in IE Developer toolbar -> Network tab -> details -> initiator
programmatically (from host of webbrowser control), or via javascript?
I know about http header 'X-Download-Initiator', my question is about source, at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as far as I know, this information is not available via any public API. You can set the feature control key so that the `X-Download-Initiator` header is emitted, but that's the *only* initiator information that can be exposed.

Comment: thank you a lot. If you don't mind i will wait for Andy answer. If he will keep the silence, your answer will be marked as correct.

Comment: Alas Eric is correct there is no public API to get the source location for downloads in IE.